# Nodejs Cannot get response.body's variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I can access the body of the response but I cannot access the body.success

```js
userInfo:function (req,res) {

        var users = [];
        db.Users.find({},function (err,result) {


            result.forEach(function (user) {
                users.push(user);
            });

            res.json({success:true, userList:users});

        });

    }
```

```js
info:function (req,res) {
        var options = { method: 'GET',
            url: config.auth_url + '/info',
            headers:
                {
                    'cache-control': 'no-cache'
                },
            form:
                {}
        };

        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error)
                throw new Error(error);
            else if (body.success)
                res.json(response.body);
            else
                res.json({success: false, code: 404});

        });

    }
```

This is the response.body

```
{"success":true,"userList":["5895ea3849616b05d89e27ce","58989c0abe93e41816b91eaf","5899e9bfadf35729818b52b7"]}
```

Is anyone have idea that I can return appropriate json date because I think that its not a valid json so that it give error.

For the Error :

```
response.body.success = undefined;
```

Comment: if the body is still in string form (json) then of course you can't access a property that doesn't exist.

Comment: What do you see if you do *console.log(body)*?

Comment: Did you try **JSON.parse(body)**?

Comment: Thanks for the help @SantanuBiswas it worked

Comment: @Mehmetali Glad I could help. I have posted my comment as answer. Pls consider accepting/upvoting it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.parse(body)` will solve your problem as needed.